# Unable to access to repository - SVN with Jenkins

Tags: svn, jenkins

I am trying to explore Jenkins and want to run by executable file upon any commit done to the repository. I am using subversion plugin in Jenkins and TortoiseSVN. I have created a repository in my local machine and trying to access that from Jenkins. Repository URL is mentioned as `file:///C:/Sample/Repository`.

But I am getting error

> Unable to access to repository

I have also tried to add password in `passwd` file in repository and username and authentication level in `authz` file in repository.

Please help to create user and password to Jenkins in my Tortoise SVN repository.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Under which user does Jenkins run? Is that one allowed to read the directory containing your repository? Is the repository a _checkout_ from a server, or is it really the complete repository? Maybe try with the server URL first?

Comment: @StephenKing Thanks for your reply.
I am running Jenkins under default admin account. Tried to use server name in the URL - but didn't work.

How can I check whether jenkins admin account has read access to directory?

Comment: @StephenKing Thanks for your reply.
My repository is in the same server - just make an empty folder as repository and imported a couple of sample files to test the jenkins enviroment with svn integration.

How can I check whether jenkins admin account has read access to directory?

Comment: But is `C:/Sample/Repository` really a server-side repository or a checkout? Don't know, how you can check permissions on Windows.